# Choose folder from tree of folders in s3 using Bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have files which existing under s3 path like below:
s3://ttttt/2018/11/01/02 -->(tttt=s3 bucket, 2018=year, 11=moth, 01=day, hour=02)

I have a new files all the time which inserted in s3 as the example below:

```
s3://tttt/2018/10/01/01/ls.s3.4cede5e7d25c.2018-10-01T01.00.tag_lre.txt.gz 
s3://tttt/2018/10/01/01/ls.s3.4cede5e7d25c.2018-10-01T01.00.tag_lre.txt.gz
s3://tttt/2018/10/01/02/ls.s3.4cede5e7d25c.2018-10-01T02.00.tag_lre.txt.gz
```

I would like to pick up via Bash script:
1. max year
2. max month
3. max day
4. max hour

The script that I built seems like that (but does not work good):

```
#!/bin/bash
result=`aws s3 ls "s3://tttt/2018/" | awk '{print $2}' |tail -n 1` 
result1=`aws s3 ls "s3://tttt/2018/${result:0:2}/" | awk '{print $NF-1}' |tail -n 1` 
result2=2018/${result:0:2}/${result1:0:2}/
```

Any ideas how to write it?

Comment: Amazon S3 always lists objects in alphabetical order. Given your filename format, wouldn't the answer always be on the last line, so it would just be a matter of extracting the elements from that line?

Answer (score 0):

Can did not show the output of `aws s3 ls "s3://tttt/2018/"|tail -1`.
With

```
result="s3://tttt/2018/10/01/01/ls.s3.4cede5e7d25c.2018-10-01T01.00.tag_lre.txt.gz"
```

you can do

```
IFS=/ read -r s3 empty bucket year month day hour file <<< "${result}"
```

result:

```
set | egrep "bucket=|year=|month=|day=|hour="
bucket=tttt
day=01
hour=01
month=10
year=2018
```